# What do DNA crystals look like?

Tags: recrystallization, dna-rna

I had about 5 ug DNA suspended in water, which I dried thoroughly in a vacufuge.

I obtained a whitish crystal (very similar to table salt, although the structure seems uneven and it's hard to tell) at the bottom of my wells, apparently of about 30 ul volume (I am not counting the dead space in between bits of crystals).

Is this crystal DNA? Or is it some sort of salt that was bound to the DNA? It was my understanding that DNA is very hard to precipitate without using ethanol (I didn't) but it seems I precipitated something anyway.

The DNA came from a prep (a Qiagen kit), so it's highly pure - the A260-A280 ratio is about 1.8.